# Korrekte Aussprache von (Hamburg-) Schnelsen

Tags: pronunciation

ich ziehe in ein paar Tagen nach Ellerbek, einem Dorf, das westlich an Hamburg-Schnelsen grenzt. Jetzt würde ich meinen neuen Hamburger Nachbarstadtteil gerne korrekt hamburgisch aussprechen. :-) (Ich komme ursprünglich aus dem süddeutschen Raum.)

Welches ist nun die korrekte Aussprache des Stadtteils: [ʃneːlsən] (langes, geschlossenes "e") wie [hier](https://de.forvo.com/word/schnelsen/#de) zu hören) oder [ʃnɛlsən] (kurzes offenes "ä").

Ich meine, schon beide Formen gehört zu haben und habe immer, die mit dem langen "e" für die korrekte gehalten, bin aber stutzig geworden als ich die Aussprache auf Forvo gehört habe. Sind beide Aussprachevarianten möglich? Ist eine davon hochdeutsch und die andere missingsch/platt?

Comment: Kurzes ä und e unterscheiden sich norddeutsch nicht. Der Verkehrsfunk des NDR sagt Schnel**l**sen. Der kommt aus Hamburg. Wenn die es nicht wissen…

Comment: Beides gängig, beides richtig.

Comment: In den Verkehrsmeldungen des NDR wird das mit einem kurzen ä ausgesprochen. Das würde ich als Hochdeutsch ansehen.

Comment: Danke für Eure Antworten!

Comment: Die Verkehrsmeldungen im Radio sind  kein besonders gutes  Argument für eine richtige Aussprache eines Ortsnamens. Der beste Gegenbeweis ist, wenn Radiosprecher des SDR versuchen, einen Stau in "Owen" (30km vom Sendezentrum) zu verkünden...

Answer (score 2):

Ich komme aus Hamburg und da gefühlt ständig Stau auf der Autobahn Richtung Schnelsen ist, hört man das öfters im Radio. Dort sprechen sie das 'e' auch kurz aus, also wie *Schnellsen*.

Comment: *Gefühlt ständig* - also eingebildet? Wie fühlt man Stau?

Comment: @userunknown: Ich kenne L.S. zwar nicht, und finde den Satz stilistisch auch nicht besonders wertvoll, aber »gefühlt ständig Stau« bedeutet: Man hat das Gefühl, dass ständig Stau ist, weiß aber, dass es in Wahrheit auch Zeiten gibt, in denen der Verkehr frei fließen kann. Eingebildet? Ja, und dessen ist sich der Sprecher auch bewusst. Genau das soll ja mit »gefühlt« ausgedrückt werden. Den Stau fühlen? Nein! »Gefühlt« bezieht sich nicht auf »Stau« sondern auf »ständig«. Aber wie gesagt: Ich will L.S. nicht zu sehr verteidigen, weil man das anders besser formulieren hätte können.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich weiß, was es bedeuten soll. Dass sich *gefühlt* auf *ständig* beziehen soll ist ein Quarkargument. *Ständig* allein kann man gar nicht fühlen. Fühlen kann man nur in der Gegenwart. Die Floskel ist einfach idiotisch aber nicht nur hier und in Bezug auf Staus.

Answer (score 0):

Ich tendiere zu der Aussprache, die du auch verlinkt hast. Das habe ich schon sehr oft so gehört, das fehlende zweite L spricht auch dafür und, bestes Argument, ich weiß :D, meine Mutter, die ihr ganzes Leben in Hamburg gewohnt hat, kennt es auch nicht anders.

Comment: Da bin ich jetzt ein bisschen verwirrt: Du bevorzugst die Aussprache, wie sie auf Forvo zu hören ist? Das ist aber jene mit einem kurzen Vokal in der ersten Silbe. Also so wie man es intuitiv aussprechen würde wenn sich der Stadtteil mit Doppel-L schriebe. Ist das korrekt?

Comment: Wenns nur um die Aussprache geht, ja, dann bevorzuge ich das von Forvo :)

Comment: Okay, es zeichnet sich eine deutliche Mehrheit für die Version mit dem kurzen E ab. :-)